# MySQL safe mode error even when using the primary key in a where clause

Tags: mysql

Many times before, when I've tried to set/update/delete something in a mySQL table, it gives

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

I can get around that by including a true condition involving the primary key, in a where clause.

However, why does the following NOT work?

```
UPDATE Lifts 
INNER JOIN liftstemp on Lifts.LiftID = liftstemp.LiftID
SET Lifts.AnnualNoLoadTestDate = liftstemp.AnnualNoLoadTestDate
where Lifts.LiftID<>"";
```

The LiftID is a varchar and is the primary key.

UPDATE: As suggested by Bill Karwin, I temporarily disabled safe mode and got an EXPLAIN report, but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

[image]

FINAL UPDATE: Turns out it was probably a version issue. I was running mariadb on that machine. On another machine with mySQL proper, it worked without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates says:

> It is possible for UPDATE and DELETE statements to produce an error in safe-updates mode even with a key specified in the WHERE clause, if the optimizer decides not to use the index on the key column...

Get an EXPLAIN report for the query, and I predict you'll see it doing `type: ALL` on one or the other table.

---

I created a table like yours, and filled it with 2000 rows. I set `sql_safe_updates=1`, and I tried your UPDATE.

No error or warning.

I tested on MySQL 5.7.27.

Also, the EXPLAIN you show is not what I get when I run EXPLAIN on the query you showed. I'm starting to guess you are not showing the query that results in the error.

Comment: Thanks, but just putting "explain" at the start of the query doesn't help, as it still just gives that same error.

Comment: You may have to disable safe updates temporarily to run the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Thanks, got an EXPLAIN report, but am not sure how to interpret it?

Comment: It is the query, copied and pasted from MySQL workbench. But I wonder if it has something to do with MySQL versions. Will test more and update.